# Code first w/existing database vs Database first and concurrent development with version control

Tags: svn, version-control, entity-framework-6

I have been using EF6.x for quite some time and am very comfortable with it.  However, as with most projects involving a team you have to stop every so often to "fix" something in the main branch (master branch/trunk etc) due to a bug or production change of some sort.  If your code involves an Entity data model and your make changes related to a DB schema change, things can get messy if you're making these changes in trunk and trying to do an catch-up merge back into a development branch that has already been started.  This has been my experience with using the DB-first approach, which includes the EF designer diagram.

After reading through various posts on the subject, I started to revisit the code-first approach w/existing database.  However, the above situation is fairly common, at least for our team.  When its just C# or javascript, changes are relatively easy to merge over into a dev branch, not so with the EDMX file and other EF-related artifacts.

With code-first, if a DB-schema change is to be handled in your main branch (production fix etc), then it seems my options are:
(1) make the updates to the EF-related classes myself and possibly use EF migrations, or...
(2) run through the EF-model reverse engineer process again, overwriting whats there.  If you keep the model name the same you will first have to delete the existing files, else the wizard will complain.

With database-first, it seems im limited on doing this type of thing, due to the merge conflicts that will result.  So the only option is to work only in a single branch and only code-related changes can be done in the mainline branch if you want to avoid merge issues.

If your team is working with Entity Framework and version control of some sort (which hopefully you are), how are you managing changes in this pretty common scenario?

[ **update** ] 
Thanks to Erik, I think I have a solution.
I had come across this as well, but didnt see much regarding the "round trip" ability after the 1st reverse engineer step.  So I just went ahead and create a small dummy database along with a dummy console app with a class library.  Then I pulled in this Reverse poco template ... changed one of the columns in the db, updated the tt file and soon as i saved (as mentioned in the tt file), my schema changes were reflected in the POCO classes.  Awesome - this is probably my ticket to dumping the edmx file which I never use anyway and will likely enable code merging between branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use EF Reverse Poco template which just updates existing classes, and the code updates are easy to merge. Give it a try.